# Как сохранить Fullscreen при переходе на другую страницу сайта?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пользуюсь плагином `Fullscreen` все работает, мне нужно чтобы после открытия страницы на весь экран, это положение сохранялось при переходе на другую страницу( например как по клику на кнопку F11 ) потому что теперь при переходе на другую страницу сайта `Fullscreen` не работает.

Не могу сделать проверку когда `Fullscreen` открыт на весь экран, а когда нет.

Хочу записывать куки и при переходе на другую страницу, если есть куки автоматически открывать страницу на весь экран.

```js
var toggleFullScreen = {
  init: function() {
    if ((window.screenfull !== undefined) && screenfull.enabled) {
      $('#toggleFullScreen').on('click', function(e) {
        screenfull.toggle(window.document[0]);
        $('body').toggleClass('fullScreen');
        e.preventDefault();
      });
    } else {
      $('#toggleFullScreen').addClass('hidden');
    }
  }
};

toggleFullScreen.init();

/*!
 * screenfull
 * v1.1.1 - 2013-11-20
 * https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js
 * (c) Sindre Sorhus; MIT License
 */
/*global Element */
(function(window, document) {
  'use strict';

  var keyboardAllowed = typeof Element !== 'undefined' && 'ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT' in Element, // IE6 throws without typeof check

    fn = (function() {
      var val, valLength;
      var fnMap = [
        [
          'requestFullscreen',
          'exitFullscreen',
          'fullscreenElement',
          'fullscreenEnabled',
          'fullscreenchange',
          'fullscreenerror'
        ],
        // new WebKit
        [
          'webkitRequestFullscreen',
          'webkitExitFullscreen',
          'webkitFullscreenElement',
          'webkitFullscreenEnabled',
          'webkitfullscreenchange',
          'webkitfullscreenerror'

        ],
        // old WebKit (Safari 5.1)
        [
          'webkitRequestFullScreen',
          'webkitCancelFullScreen',
          'webkitCurrentFullScreenElement',
          'webkitCancelFullScreen',
          'webkitfullscreenchange',
          'webkitfullscreenerror'

        ],
        [
          'mozRequestFullScreen',
          'mozCancelFullScreen',
          'mozFullScreenElement',
          'mozFullScreenEnabled',
          'mozfullscreenchange',
          'mozfullscreenerror'
        ],
        [
          'msRequestFullscreen',
          'msExitFullscreen',
          'msFullscreenElement',
          'msFullscreenEnabled',
          'MSFullscreenChange',
          'MSFullscreenError'
        ]
      ];
      var i = 0;
      var l = fnMap.length;
      var ret = {};

      for (; i < l; i++) {
        val = fnMap[i];
        if (val && val[1] in document) {
          for (i = 0, valLength = val.length; i < valLength; i++) {
            ret[fnMap[0][i]] = val[i];
          }
          return ret;
        }
      }
      return false;
    })(),

    screenfull = {
      request: function(elem) {
        var request = fn.requestFullscreen;

        elem = elem || document.documentElement;

        // Work around Safari 5.1 bug: reports support for
        // keyboard in fullscreen even though it doesn't.
        // Browser sniffing, since the alternative with
        // setTimeout is even worse.
        if (/5\.1[\.\d]* Safari/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
          elem[request]();
        } else {
          elem[request](keyboardAllowed && Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
        }
      },
      exit: function() {
        document[fn.exitFullscreen]();
      },
      toggle: function(elem) {
        if (this.isFullscreen) {
          this.exit();
        } else {
          this.request(elem);
        }
      },
      onchange: function() {},
      onerror: function() {},
      raw: fn
    };

  if (!fn) {
    window.screenfull = false;
    return;
  }

  Object.defineProperties(screenfull, {
    isFullscreen: {
      get: function() {
        return !!document[fn.fullscreenElement];
      }
    },
    element: {
      enumerable: true,
      get: function() {
        return document[fn.fullscreenElement];
      }
    },
    enabled: {
      enumerable: true,
      get: function() {
        // Coerce to boolean in case of old WebKit
        return !!document[fn.fullscreenEnabled];
      }
    }
  });

  document.addEventListener(fn.fullscreenchange, function(e) {
    screenfull.onchange.call(screenfull, e);
  });

  document.addEventListener(fn.fullscreenerror, function(e) {
    screenfull.onerror.call(screenfull, e);
  });

  window.screenfull = screenfull;
})(window, document);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="toggleFullScreen">Открыть на весь экран</a>
```

Comment: А в faq этого плагина случайно не то, что Вы хотите? https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js#faq

Comment: Я на английском языке не очень понимаю.